# ¿como sumar las filas de un datagridview siempre que cumplan una condición y mostrar la suma en textbox C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

quisiera sumar las filas de un datagridview pero solo si cumplen una condición, la condición en cuestión es por ejemplo, "**suma solo las filas de el datagridview si el valor de la columna 'cantidad' es <= a 10**". algo parecido a "*Registros.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();*" pero que cuente solo los que cumplen la condición. si alguien me puede ayudar por favor. muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no ofrece todos los datos necesarios para resolver la interpretacion del código ` Registros.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();`  cuidaremos siemprede todos

Comment: No amigo, Registros.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString(); es la manera de contar todas la filas de un datagridview, pero lo que yo quiero contar solo las que cumplan la condición.

Comment: La forma en que podrias hacer eso, es recorriendo todas las filas del `DataGridView` y verificando una a una la condición y si se cumple incrementas la suma, te recomiendo mirar [como preguntar]  (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), has un esfuerzo, muestra lo que intentaste y entonces alguien te podrá ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una cosa es sumar el contenido de las  filas y otra es contar las filas, lo que entiendo es que quieres sumar la columna "Total", si es asi tienes que recorrer el grid e ir acumulando el valor de la fila cuando se cumpla la condicion, algo asi:

```
 int Total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= dgv1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                Valor = covert.todouble(dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString())
        if (Valor < 10)
                {
                    Total = Total + 1;
                }
            }
txtTotal.Text = Total;
```

Comment: De hecho si buscaba sumar las filas amigo, disculpa por mi mala expresión.

Comment: por ejemplo, si tengo 10 filas y tengo 5 que cumplen la condición, entonces que mi resultado sea 5 (osea las 5 filas que si cumplieron la condición).

Comment: El ejemplo de codigo que te deje te sirve para eso, cuando cumpla la condicion suma  (Total = Total +1) en la variable Total

Comment: No me ha funcionado amigo jejeje, me imprime de igual forma todas las filas

Comment: Puedes poner el fragmento de codigo que recorre el grid y la asignacion del valor al texbox?

Comment: Lo puse así, no se si entendí bien:

Comment: double Total = 0;                         
        var _IndexFila = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[_IndexFila].Cells["ColTotal"].Value) < 10)
            {
                 Total = Total +1;
            }
            
        }
        Total.Text = Total;

Comment: edite mi respuesta, intenta con ese codigo

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya quedo listo, te agradezco.